# Dynamically wrap words in <em> with different startpoint

Tags: jquery

I want to wrap words inside a < h1> dynamically with a < em> using jQuery with 2 variables:

- Number of words
- Startpoint, like nth, but within the < h1> tag

I have some so far:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $('.my-heading h1').html(function (i, html) {
        return html.replace(/(\w+\s\w+)/, '<em>$1</em>')   
        });

});
```

This code wraps the first two words inside a < em>, but I need it to have this code more variable so that I can insert the number of words that should be wrapped and the starting point. For example it should start at word number 4 and wrap 3 words inside a < em>.

Any ideas?

Comment: How does number of words come into play?

Comment: @HoldOffHunger, please see the solution below, this is the answer to my question. The number of words does not come into play in my code, thats the problem :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no build-ins in javascript or jquery to do this,
The simple solution will be:

```js
var start = 2;
var count = 5;
$('h1').html(function(i, html){ 
    var words = $(this).text().split(' ');
    var final = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < start && i < words.length; i++) 
        final += words[i] + ' ';
    final += '<em>';
    for (; i < start + count && i < words.length; i++)
        final +=  words[i] + ' ';
    final += '</em>';
    for (; i < words.length - 1; i++)
        final += words[i] + ' ';
    final += words[words.length - 1];
    return final;
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>The em element You have to hurry up! We cannot live like this.</h1>
```

This is basically - itereate through the text until `start`, append `'<em>'` to the final html, then iterate until `start + count`, append `'</em>'`, then iterate until end of string.

Answer (score 1):

I created a function, with a [working demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sugyvLcj/), that you can use.

You can re-run it with different params to change which words are wrapped as often as you like.  It will also work if the start index and/or number of words go out of bounds as well.

```
function dynamicWrap(target, start_idx, words){
        // if a string target was given then convert it to a jQuery object
    if(typeof target === 'string'){
            target = $(target);
    }
    // make sure start_idx and words are numbers
    start_idx = start_idx * 1;
    words = words * 1;
    // loop thru each target element
    $.each(target, function(idx, ele){    
            var eleObj = $(ele);
        // split the text contents into an array of words
        var txtArr = eleObj.text().trim().split(/\s+/);        
        
        // These next two arrays will be used to store sections of the overall txtArr
        var beg = []; // these words are never wrapped
        var mid = []; // these words are always wrapped
        // and any remiaining in the txtArr will never be wrapped either
        
        
        if(start_idx === 0){            
            // pull out the words contained in the txtArr between index 0 and {words variable value}
          mid = txtArr.splice(0, words <= txtArr.length ? words : txtArr.length);          
        } else if(start_idx <= txtArr.length){          
          beg = txtArr.splice(0, start_idx <= txtArr.length ? start_idx : txtArr.length);
          mid = txtArr.splice(0, words <= txtArr.length ? words : txtArr.length);
        }
        
        eleObj.html( beg.join(' ') + ' <em>' + mid.join(' ') + '</em> ' + txtArr.join(' '));
        
        
    });
}
```

Comment: Works great, thanks a lot, after testing both I am going for the more simple code above for now, but I might need this one too if I need to repeat things and switch to this code.